# Monitoring iBeacon beacons in background

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon

I've been developing an iOS app and playing around with Apple's `CoreLocation` and `iBeacon` technology. So far I used three beacons with different UUIDs. Everything was ok until I decided to add more beacons to my app. Only then I ran into strange issue. It's been said, a single app can monitor up to 20 beacon regions at once, when in the background - however in my particular case, this number seems to be 3. I tried different approaches, nothing worked. When I shuffled beacons in their array the outcome was as I expected - only the first 3 beacon regions triggered `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` events when app was in background. This didn't applied when it was in foreground.

Please consider this:

1. I have an array of custom beacon objects (consumed from API)
2. For each custom beacon object I create an instance of `CLBeaconRegion` like so:

   ```
   let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: region.uuid)!, identifier: region.uuid)

   beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
   beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = true
   beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true
   ```
3. Then I pass that instance to CLLocationManager's `startMonitoringForRegion` method like so:

   locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)

When looping through CLLocationManager's `monitoredRegions` method response I get all the beacon regions I expected with regionState 2 (outside)

4. On top of that I've already added:

   NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

to app's Info.plist

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

to ViewController's viewDidLoad method

Still, `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` trigger only when I'm in range of any of the first three beacon regions I started monitoring for.

Thanks,

Piotr Czarnoleski

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**An iOS device has a limited number of hardware acceleration slots** for beacon detection.  These slots defer to the bluetooth chip to notify the operating system when a beacon region pattern has been matched.  When these slots are used, background detections are very quick -- a region entry event can happen within a second or two of the beacon transmission being in range.

If these slots run out, however, then the operating system must fall back to full scans to find the remaining regions.  The operating system throttles these to save battery.  Evidence suggests that they take place about every 15 minutes.  This means that if any regions monitored by your app that don't get a hardware acceleration slot can take up to 15 minutes to be detected after a matching beacon comes into range (although on average it will often take less time -- 7.5 minutes would be the average)

How many hardware slots are available?  This is undocumented and may vary by iOS device model.  But experimentation shows it may be about 30.  This is across all apps on the phone and is completely unrelated to the 20 region limit per app.  The first apps to register regions are the first apps to get the slots.

Read more here: https://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/04/21/max-beacon-regions-ios.html

It is possible that the above is what you are experiencing, and **there are only 3 hardware acceleration slots left on your phone for your app**.  To test this theory, you can:

1. Uninstall other apps that you expect may be registering beacon regions, which should free up more slots.
2. Wait up to 15 minutes to see if you get detections for the other regions in the background.

Comment: David, the info about hardware-accelerated beacon region slots is fascinating. Can you share the source of that info? I'd love to be able to read more.

Comment: @davidyoung thanks! I tried both proposed test cases - first I waited about 15 minutes with my app in the background and the didEnterRegion triggered. It is definitely hardware acceleration slots issue as I repeated the whole process again and the same thing happened. Freeing up more slots however, didn't work for me - I uninstalled all beacon related apps and rebooted my iPhone, but I still have only 3 available hardware acceleration slots. I suspect this might be what iPhone 4s is capable off. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Interesting.  Yes, it is possible that the 4s only has 3 slots (You could try rebooting, factory reset, etc to be sure.).  If true, this is a hardware limitation and the only workaround would be to reduce your region usage to 3.

Comment: @Duncan-C see the link in my answer for the experiment that led to this theory.

Answer (score 0):

Core Location lets you monitor a total of 20 `CLRegion`s per app. Both beacon regions and geofence regions count against that 20 region limit.

In order to monitor beacons in the background you will need to add the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key to your info.plist, as well as calling the location manager's `requestAlwaysAuthorization` method at startup if you don't already have an authorization status of `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways`.

Beyond that you're going to have to post more information about the details of your app, the relevant code, and debugging information in order for us to help you.

Note that you can use the location manager's `monitoredRegions` property to get a list of the regions your app is currently monitoring. I suggest checking that, as well as the `authorizationStatus`, to see what's going on.

Comment: thanks for quick response. I've updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

This link have both ibeacon sender and receiver app in swift 2.3. Hopefully this will give you clear idea about ibeacons.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0ixmynkjet0uwj/ibeacons_final%202.zip?dl=0